# Split a string into token in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, split

```
struct string {
    size_t length;
    size_t allocated;
    char* data;
};
    string* strCreate(char* str) {...}
string* strSubstring(string* str, size_t pos, size_t len) {...}
char* strGet(string* str) {
    return str->data;
}
size_t findFrist(string* str, char what, size_t pos) {
    for(size_t i = pos; i < str->length; ++i) {
        if(str->data[i] == what)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
string** strTokenizer(string* str) {
    string** res;
    res = malloc(sizeof(char*)*90); //*90 (token num)
    for(int i=0; i<90; i++) //i<90 (token num)
        res[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100); //*100 (a token lenght)
    size_t first = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(first < str->length) {
        int second = findFrist(str,' ',first);
        if(second == - 1)
            second = str->length;
        string* token = strSubstring(str,first, second - first);
        if(*strGet(token) != ' ')
            res[i] = token;
        first = second + 1;
        ++i;
    }
    return res;
}
int main() {
    string* fe = strCreate("A string \ tof");
    string** r = strTokenizer(fe);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%s",strGet(r[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a string tokenizer. When I want to print the string in the `main` function it not print the `\`. The other thing is that how to allocate `string** res` in proper way. When I allocate for the `sizeof(char*)` the only way that I see is loop through the string, but I was just wondering is this possible to allocate without going through the string 2 times in the tokenizer function.

I do not want to use `strtok`

`typedef struct string string` in the .h file

Comment: You need to loop to allocate, but why are you allocating 100 bytes for each struct when they’re probably 12 bytes each? Or why even have them as dynamically allocated if the data in them is dynamically allocated? Except you later overwrite the pointers with something else from a function we can’t even see here. This looks like quite complicated and can’t say anything if it’s not [mcve]

Comment: Note that you need `typedef struct string string;` (or equivalent) somewhere near the top to be able to compile the code with a C compiler rather than a C++ compiler.  (You might also fix `Frist` to `First` and `lenght` to `length`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know that this is the str.c file, int main() in the main.c file. I not copy the .h file

Comment: Showing code that doesn't compile does not earn brownie points.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: your program cannot be compiled with out doing modifications of `typedef`  of `struct string` and few functions are missing definitions like `strCreate`, `strSubstring`. Its good to provide minimal compliable and executable, so that people can try online etc

Comment: Note that the string `"A string \ tof"` is malformed — your compiler should be warning you about it.  If you want a backslash in a string, you write (for example), `"A string \\ tof"`.  Backslash-space has no defined meaning; it is probably being interpreted as a single space.  Maybe you should print the argument to `strCreate()` to validate this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if I use \\ it just print \ so it it working, thanks

Comment: Now I added stringCreate and strSubsrting as well

Comment: Why are you using constants like `90` and `100` etc, what is the significance of those? Instead define macros with meaning full names and use it, it improves readability. Also its not clear what is the delimiter you using for tokenizing , is it the ` `(space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling the code using GCC 10.2.0 with options:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror …
```

I get the message:

```
bs83.c:85:44: error: unknown escape sequence: '\040' [-Werror]
   85 |     string *fe = strCreate("A string \ tof");
```

As I noted in the comments, the string `"A string \ tof"` is malformed — your compiler should be warning you about it. If you want a backslash in a string, you write (for example), `"A string \\ tof"`. Backslash-space has no defined meaning; it is probably being interpreted as a single space. Maybe you should print the argument to `strCreate()` to validate this.

You also need `typedef struct string string;` near the top of the code for it to compile with a C compiler (and the headers).

Here is a fixed version of your code — because of the compilation options I use, the functions need to be either `static` or declared before being defined; I make them `static` since the only reason to make them non-`static` (IMO) is if they're accessed from another source file, and then they'd be declared in a header.  That probably applies to your code — there is mention of a header.

Here's fixed code that works:

```
/* SO 6537-9584 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct string string;

struct string
{
    size_t length;
    size_t allocated;
    char *data;
};

static
string *strCreate(char *str)
{
    string *s = malloc(sizeof(string));
    s->length = strlen(str);
    s->allocated = s->length * 2;
    s->data = (char *)malloc(s->allocated + 1);
    memcpy(s->data, str, s->length);
    s->data[s->length] = '\0';
    return s;
}

static
string *strSubstring(string *str, size_t pos, size_t len)
{
    string *s = malloc(sizeof(string));
    s->length = len;
    s->allocated = s->length * 2;
    s->data = (char *)malloc(s->allocated + 1);
    memcpy(s->data, &str->data[pos], s->length);
    s->data[s->length] = '\0';
    return s;
}

static
char *strGet(string *str)
{
    return str->data;
}

static
size_t findFirst(string *str, char what, size_t pos)
{
    for (size_t i = pos; i < str->length; ++i)
    {
        if (str->data[i] == what)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

static
string **strTokenizer(string *str)
{
    string **res;
    res = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 90); // *90 (token num)
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) // i<90 (token num)
        res[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // *100 (a token length)
    size_t first = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (first < str->length)
    {
        int second = findFirst(str, ' ', first);
        if (second == -1)
            second = str->length;
        string *token = strSubstring(str, first, second - first);
        if (*strGet(token) != ' ')
            res[i] = token;
        first = second + 1;
        ++i;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    string *fe = strCreate("A string \\ tof");
    string **r = strTokenizer(fe);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("[[%s]]\n", strGet(r[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
[[A]]
[[string]]
[[\]]
[[tof]]
```

Note the use of `[[` and `]]` around the printed strings (and the newlines).  It makes it easier to identify trailing blanks and embedded carriage return characters and various other mishaps.